# Migrating `int` to `bigint` in PostgresSQL without any downtime?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, downtime

I have a database that is going to experience the [integer exhaustion problem](https://m.signalvnoise.com/update-on-basecamp-3-being-stuck-in-read-only-as-of-nov-8-922am-cst/) that Basecamp famously faced back in November. I have several months to figure out what to do.

Is there a no-downtime-required, proactive solution to migrating this column type? If so what is it? If not, is it just a matter of eating the downtime and migrating the column when I can?

Is [this article sufficient](https://tech.coffeemeetsbagel.com/schema-migration-from-int-to-bigint-on-a-massive-table-in-postgres-aabb835c3b84), assuming I have several days/weeks to perform the migration **now** before I'm forced to do it when I run out of ids?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html).

With logical replication you can have different data types at primary and standby.

Copy the schema with `pg_dump -s`, change the data types on the copy and then start logical replication.

Once all data is copied over, switch the application to use the standby.

For zero down time, the application has to be able to reconnect and retry, but that's always a requirement in such a case.

You need PostgreSQL v10 or better for that, and your database

- shouldn't modify the schema, as DDL is not replicated.
- should not use sequence (`SERIAL` or `IDENTITY`), as the last used value would not be [replicated](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-restrictions.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help, edits, and multiple answers!

Answer (score 5):

Another solution for pre-v10 databases *where all transactions are short*:

- Add a `bigint` column to the table.
- Create a `BEFORE` trigger that sets the new column whenever a row is added or updated.
- Run a series of updates that set the new column from the old one where it `IS NULL`. Keep those batches short so you don't lock long and don't deadlock much. Make sure these transaction run with `session_replication_role = replica` so they don't trigger triggers.
- Once all rows are updated, create a unique index `CONCURRENTLY` on the new column.
- Add a unique constraint `USING` the index you just created. That will be fast.
- Perform the switch:

  ```
  BEGIN;
  ALTER TABLE ... DROP oldcol;
  ALTER TABLE ... ALTER newcol RENAME TO oldcol;
  COMMIT;
  ```

  That will be fast.

Your new column has no `NOT NULL` set. This cannot be done without a long invasive lock. But you can add a check constraint `IS NOT NULL` and create it `NOT VALID`. That is good enough, and you can later validate it without disruptions.

If there are foreign key constraints, things get a little more complicated. You have to drop these and create `NOT VALID` foreign keys to the new column.

Comment: Update rows in batches with [`loop_execute()`](https://github.com/rin-nas/postgresql-patterns-library/blob/master/procedures/loop_execute/).

Answer (score 2):

Create a copy of the old table but with modified ID field. Next create a trigger on the old table that inserts new data to both tables. Finally copy data from the old table to the new one (it would be a good idea to distinguish pre-trigger data with post-trigger for example by id if it is sequential). Once you are done switch tables and delete the old one.

This obviously requires twice as much space (and time for copy) but will work without **any** downtime.